# How o use backgroundworker withp rogressbar in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

at the top :

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
```

in constructor :

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bgw.DoWork += Bgw_DoWork;
            bgw.ProgressChanged += Bgw_ProgressChanged;
            bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }
```

the events :

```
private void Bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var filesl = GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.*");
            foreach (var item in filesl)
            {

                bgw.ReportProgress(0,item);

                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(item);
                if (File.Exists(info.FullName))
                {
                    dic.Add(item, info.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Content = e.UserState as string;
        }

        private void Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

starting the background worker :

```
if (startWatching)
                {
                    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
                 }
```

but what it does now the application still freezing and when it's ending doing the foreach loop then it's showing the label1 the last file name and i wanted it to be async and to display on the label1 all the files(item).

The GetFiles method :

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
        {
            Stack<string> pending = new Stack<string>();
            pending.Push(root);
            while (pending.Count != 0)
            {
                var path = pending.Pop();
                string[] next = null;
                try
                {
                    next = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);
                }
                catch { }
                if (next != null && next.Length != 0)
                    foreach (var file in next) yield return file;
                try
                {
                    next = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                    foreach (var subdir in next) pending.Push(subdir);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

What i want to do is to report progress and display each file when adding the files to the dic(dictionary) on a label and also to report progress percentages to progressBar1 (i already added a progressBar1 control).

what takes a lot of time to do is the GetFiles but much more time is the foreach loop :

```
foreach (var item in filesl)
                {
                    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(item);
                    if (File.Exists(info.FullName))
                    {
                        dic.Add(item, info.Length);
                    }
                }
```

that is why i want to use a backgroundworker to show the user the first progress in the application first getting the files and then starting the second progress.

Comment: Are you aware that you can traverse an entire directory tree with the [Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefilesystementries?view=net-6.0#system-io-directory-enumeratefilesystementries(system-string-system-string-system-io-searchoption)) method?

Comment: This code has a firehose bug, it calls ReportProgress() too often.  Likely to happen with a solid-state drive or when running the program more than once, as is common while testing it, with file data stored in the file system cache.  At its core it is a UI design mistake, the label displays text that changes so fast that no human can ever read it.  A progress bar isn't all that useful either since you can't predict how long the operation is going to take.

Comment: Consider not writing this code at all and leaving the job up to the [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory?view=net-6.0#microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-filesystem-copydirectory(system-string-system-string-microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-uioption-microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-uicanceloption)) progress graph that Windows Explorer uses.

Comment: @HansPassant what i wanted to do is to avoid the user from being waiting too long when it's doing the foreach loop. the foreach loop takes too long.  i didn't understand how to use the CopyDirectory in the link.

Comment: Using Directory.GetFiles together with yield is not the best idea. Directory.GetFiles will perform very bad. Instead use Directory.EnumerateFiles. You should use the overload that accepts a EnumerationOptions as argument. This way you avoid expensive unauthorized access exceptions to further improve the performance. It's Audi more reasonable to configure the ProgressBar to run in indeterminate mode. Better let go the old BackgroundWorker in favor of the Task library.

Comment: The File.Exist is redundant. Remove it to improve performance. Directory.GetFiles returns only existing files. Additionally, the constructor of FileInfo will throw if an inside path is passed as an argument.

Comment: But the most important fix is to replace Directory.GetFiles with Directory.EnumerateFiles and Directory.GetDirectories with Directory.EnumerateDirectories